# Slow camera capture on Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

Using Ubuntu 64 bit on a Raspberry Pi 400 I get a very slow frame rate, like 2.2 frames per second.

```
int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    do {
        double t = (double)cv::getTickCount();
        std::cout << "Tick count: " << cv::getTickCount() << std::endl;         
        cap >> img;
        key = cv::waitKey(1);
        t = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t)/cv::getTickFrequency();
        std::cout<< " Frequency: " << cv::getTickFrequency() << std::endl;
        std::cout<< "Tick: " << t << std::endl;
        std::cout<< "Rate: " << (1.0 / t)<< std::endl;
    } while(key != 27);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm not even displaying the image on screen or doing any image operation.

The same camera has a better performance when used by other apps (like cheese).
Are there mechanisms for achieving a better performance?

UPDATE: here you have my build info

> General configuration for OpenCV 4.2.0
> =====================================   Version control:               unknown
>
> Extra modules:
> Location (extra):            /build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg/contrib/modules
> Version control (extra):     unknown
>
> Platform:
> Timestamp:                   2020-10-04T07:09:34Z
> Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-118-generic aarch64
> CMake:                       3.16.3
> CMake generator:             Ninja
> CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/ninja
> Configuration:               Release
>
> CPU/HW features:
> Baseline:                    NEON FP16
> required:                  NEON
> disabled:                  VFPV3
>
> C/C++:
> Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
> C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.2.0)
> C++ flags (Release):         -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG
> C++ flags (Debug):           -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
> C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
> C flags (Release):           -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG
> C flags (Debug):             -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/opencv-f6XtMJ/opencv-4.2.0+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
> Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
> Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -Wl,--gc-sections
> ccache:                      NO
> Precompiled headers:         NO
> Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
> 3rdparty dependencies:
>
> OpenCV modules:
> To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face
> features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs
> imgproc java line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping
> photo plot python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching
> structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio
> videostab viz ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
> Disabled:                    world
> Disabled by dependency:      sfm
> Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy
> cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv gapi js
> matlab ovis python2 ts
> Applications:                apps
> Documentation:               doxygen python javadoc
> Non-free algorithms:         NO
>
> GUI:
> GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.23)
> GThread :                  YES (ver 2.66.0)
> GtkGlExt:                  NO
> OpenGL support:              NO
> VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.3.0)
>
> Media I/O:
> ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
> JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
> WEBP:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x020e)
> PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
> TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.1.0)
> OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libImath.so
> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIex.so
> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so
> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.5.3)
> GDAL:                        YES (/usr/lib/libgdal.so)
> GDCM:                        YES (3.0.7)
> HDR:                         YES
> SUNRASTER:                   YES
> PXM:                         YES
> PFM:                         YES
>
> Video I/O:
> DC1394:                      YES (2.2.6)
> FFMPEG:                      YES
> avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
> avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
> avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
> swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
> avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
> GStreamer:                   YES (1.18.0)
> PvAPI:                       NO
> v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
>
> Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.3 interface 11103)
>
> Trace:                         YES (built-in)
>
> Other third-party libraries:
> Lapack:                      NO
> Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
> Custom HAL:                  NO
> Protobuf:                    /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so (3.12.3)
>
> OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
> Include path:                /usr/include/CL
> Link libraries:              Dynamic load
>
> Python 3:
> Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.6)
> Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.6)
> numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.4)
> install path:                lib/python3.8/dist-packages
>
> Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3
>
> Java:
> ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.8)
> JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux
> /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
> Java wrappers:               YES
> Java tests:                  NO
>
> Install to:                    /usr
>
> ---

Comment: If you put back the headers you have removed, other folks might run your code. If you add `cv::getBuildInformation();` output, someone may spot an issue. If you show your compilation command with parameters, an issue may become apparent.

Comment: Might be worth changing `waitKey` to `pollKey`, `waitKey` will wait for *at least* a millisecond, it could be more. `cout` can be slow `std::endl` makes it even slower

Comment: @MarkSetchell added the build infomration.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it is not cout or endl fault. I've already tried without them and the performance was the same.

Comment: have you tried changing/removing `waitKey`? are you using compiler optimisations?

Comment: @AlanBirtles got this _error: ‘pollKey’ is not a member of ‘cv’_ I don''t know if pollKey is a new function or someting like that. Anyway, I'd say that this is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found the issue.
listing the camera resolutions I could see that there was a setting with only 2 fps, and it was when using YUYV format. I forced the input to be MJPG with `cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC ,cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G') );` and the frame rate increased to 19-20, which is still low but might be acceptable.